# Formatting of Axis label

Tags: r, ggplot2, formatting

Anyone know to format /move the x and y axis label so that it will not overlap with axis tick value name?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ft6LV.png

Here is the current code for my heatmap:

```
result<-ggplot(df_matrix, aes(x = flat_type, y = storey_range, fill = median_sales)) + 
      geom_tile() +
      facet_grid(~ estate_type, switch = "x", scales = "free_x", space = "free_x") + 
      scale_y_discrete(limits = rev(levels(as.factor(df_matrix$storey_range))))+
      theme(strip.placement = "top") +
      scale_fill_continuous(labels = dollar) + 
      scale_x_discrete("Flat Type", labels = c ("1 ROOM" = "1 RM", "2 ROOM" = "2 RM", "3 ROOM" = "3 RM", "4 ROOM" = "4 RM", "5 ROOM" = "5 RM", "EXECUTIVE" = "EXEC","MULTI-GENERATION" = "MG"))+ 
      labs(x = "Flat Type", y = "Storey Range",colour = "Average Resale Price ($)",title = "Resale Price By Flat Type and Storey")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the right margin of the y axis within the `theme` function.

```
result + theme(axis.title.y = element_text(margin=margin(r=30,"mm")))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the axis title specifically within the theme in ggplot using `hjust` and `vjust` within `element_text`.

```
mtcars%>%
    ggplot(aes(x = hp, y = disp))+
    geom_point()+
    theme(axis.title.x  = element_text(vjust = -1),
          axis.title.y = element_text(vjust = 4))
```